# How to plot an ellipse with given rotation angle in C# WPF using Oxyplot?

Tags: c#, wpf, annotations, oxyplot

OxyPlot is a cross-platform plotting library for .NET, very convenient for making plots,

Now there's a situation here, I have to draw a 95% confidence ellipse to an XY scatter plot.

Oxyplot provides with following annotation:-

[image]

Given here Ellipse Annotation(OxyPlot.Annotations) gives only following properties to add ellipse-

[image]

We don't have any rotation property or method here, IRender provides several draw methods to override but none of the methods have double angled rotation argument or so. Neither the [documentation](https://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models/annotations/index.html) has provides any direct solution to it:-

Then how to draw this:-

*I was facing this issue for one of my assignment, and came up with a solution after going through the following forums discussion to get hints on how to generate such an ellipse.

1. https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/268
2. https://oxyplot.userecho.com/en/communities/1/topics/598-ellipse-annotation-rotation

Please add more solutions if anyone else has :-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link shared (in Quest.) best and easiest solution here was to draw an ellipse using PolygonAnnotation, which takes List of co-ordinate points,

Let's say if you give four co-ordinate points A,B,C,D--- polygonAnnotation will give me a closed 4-gon~quadrilateral sort of structure based on kind of points taken.
Now if you increase the number of points from 4 to 6--- it will give you hexagon, and so on.

Now at pixel level you can give infinite-number/discrete-number of points eclipsing over 360 degree.

So here we need an algorithm/equation of point on an 2D ellipse- given following inputs (based on this case):-

1. Center of ellipse (h,k)
2. rotation angle of the ellipse axis
3. major axis (a)
4. minor axis (b)
5. theta angle from the x-axis

   ```
    private void GeneratePolygonAsEllipse(PolygonAnnotation polygonAnnotation)

    {
        double step = 2 * Math.PI / 200;
        var h = xCenter;
        var k = yCenter;
        var rotation = AngleOfRotation;
        var a = MajorAxisLength;
        var b = MinorAxisLength;

        for (double theta = 0; theta < 2 * Math.PI; theta += step)
        {
            var x = a * Math.Cos(rotation) * Math.Cos(theta) + b * Math.Sin(rotation) * Math.Sin(theta) + h;
            var y = b * Math.Cos(rotation) * Math.Sin(theta) + a * Math.Sin(rotation) * Math.Cos(theta) + k;

            polygonAnnotation.Points.Add(new DataPoint(x, y));
        }
    }
   ```

I hope above stipulated sample method equation can be useful to other folks like me looking for solution. I couldn't find direct solution anywhere else so I have added my solution here, that can be used as reference.

Result:-
[image]

if anyone can come-up with other solutions like how to use IRender or anything else, would be great to look at them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small error, you forgot a minus sign in the transformation for y. Needs to be "- a * Math.Sin(rotation)"

```
var y = b * Math.Cos(rotation) * Math.Sin(theta) - a * Math.Sin(rotation) * Math.Cos(theta) + k;
```